# Can you delete rows in BigQuery from Python script?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Hi is there a way for deleting rows in BigQuery from a Python Script? I tried looking in the documentation and finding an example on internet, but I could not find anything.

Something that looks like this.

```
table_id = "a.dataset.table"  # Table ID for faulty_gla_entry

statement = """ DELETE FROM a.dataset.table where value = 2 """

client.delete(table_id, statement)
```

Comment: Check this out - https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/usage/index.html#bigquery-basics

Comment: @SergeyGeron thank you, wrote something that works nicely!

Answer (score 1):

Like @SergeyGeron stated. https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/usage/index.html#bigquery-basics
has nice stuff.

Wrote something like this.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

query = """DELETE FROM a.dataset.table WHERE value = 4"""
query_job = client.query(query)
print(query_job.result())
```

Answer (score 1):

here you can see a code a documentation to execute a [query with python](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#complete_source_code)

You can see this example code, with the “Delete” statement.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery 
client = bigquery.Client() 
dml_statement = ( 
"Delete from dataset.Inventory where ID=5"
) 
query_job = client.query(dml_statement) # API request 
query_job.result() # Waits for statement to finish
```

How to [build queries in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax.)